# Can we write "You're the most beautiful."?

Tags: superlatives

I have a question on grammar. Which is the correct one?

> You're the most beautiful.

> You're the most beautiful girl.

Comment: The version without a noun would be acceptable in contexts where the meaning is obvious. _There are many beautiful girls here tonight, but you're the most beautiful._

Comment: Perhaps you're getting confused with article-less ***You're most beautiful*** - a slightly dated / formal / poetic way of saying *You're **very** beautiful*. A very common idiomatically established version of this usage occurs with the starchy/formal acknowledgement of a favour granted: ***You are most kind***.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you shared with us your specific concerns.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is completely error free. Go ahead with the last option since the first one is missing with a noun.